# C Language: Function interactions

Tags: c, multithreading

I was working on a piece of code and I began doubting myself on whether or not it would do what I was thinking... Right now I have 3 different files - lets call this A.(c/h) B.(c/h) C.(c/h). A.c is creating a thread that will be used to process messages that need to be published. B.c is initializing A.c by calling A.c's create() function. A.c has one other function that B.c calls which just processes some data and places it on the queue which A.c's thread processes. Everything here is working as expected...

Now what I want to do is implement C.c which will handle a callback/signal from some external piece of code. If I were to call A.c's processing and queuing function would it be the same instance of the function that B.c is using? How can I ensure that it is. I know in cpp I would toy with the idea of making it a singleton and change the design around drastically but right now that is not an option. I just want to make sure C.c will be using the only instance of A.c and all of the variables that B.c initialized.

Thanks!

Comment: You can't instantiate *source files* in C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is unclear what you are really concerned over, maybe these comments will help:

C does not have *objects* in the way OO languages, such as C++ or Objective-C, do. A C function operates on the data passed to it as arguments and/or data stored in global variables; with no object instances there are no instance variables.

So when you call a function defined in `A.c` from `C.c` it will operate on the data you pass it and any global data it accesses. When you call the same from from `B.c` it will operate on the data passed and the *same* global data, if any, that is used when it is called from `C.c`.

Maybe you are instead concerned over which *thread* the function will be called on? Well the thread will depend on the thread of the caller; if functions in `B.c` are running on a different thread to those in `C.c`, then functions in `A.c` called from `B.c` and `C.c` will run on different threads. As you primarily seemed to be concerned over variables if you are using thread-local storage then in this case the variables will be different for calls from `B.c` and `C.c` - if you don't know what thread-local storage is don't worry, you cannot use it "by accident", so it won't be an issue in your case.

HTH more than it confuses!

Comment: yes this helps! thank you. I think I was getting lost in my code. The mentioning of global variables is exactly what pulled everything together for me. Thanks!